# Converting a Maven 1 project into Maven 2

Tags: apache, maven, maven-2

I'm new to Maven, and have been running into some difficulty in a project. I am to convert a Maven 1 project into Maven 2.

I started with these files:

- maven.xml -- contains custom build scripts
- project.properties -- general build settings
- project.xml -- Project Object Model (POM) definition

From my understanding, Maven 2 project I must move these files into these:

- pom.xml -- POM definition
- (and possibly) settings.xml -- local configuration

I have gone about this by using the command **'mvn one:convert'**.

This seemed to take care of project.xml > pom.xml

I then added a  to pom.xml to include project.properties (which seemed to work).

Am I right in assuming that all I have left is to transfer over the contents of maven.xml >> pom.xml ?

maven.xml starts with:

```
<project default="site_deploy"
     xmlns:ant="jelly:ant"
     xmlns:maven="jelly:maven"
     xmlns:j="jelly:core"
     xmlns:util="jelly:util">

    <ant:property environment="env"/>
```

and contains contains goals such as:

```
<goal name="site_deploy">
    <attainGoal name="clean"/>
    <attainGoal name="clean:clean"/>
    <ant:delete dir="${maven.src.dir}/core/target" />
    <attainGoal name="core_deploy"/>
</goal>

<goal name="core">
    <maven:maven
        descriptor="core/project.xml"
        goals="jar:install"/>
      <ant:property name="m2Dir" value="${maven.repo.local}/../../.m2/repository/app/${application.version}"/>
      <ant:property name="m1Path" value="${maven.repo.local}/${application.id}/jars/${application.id}-core-${application.version}.jar"/>
      <ant:echo message="copying jar m1 to m2 (${m1Path}) to (${m2Dir})" />
      <ant:mkdir dir="${m2Dir}"/>
      <ant:copy todir="${m2Dir}" file="${m1Path}" />
</goal>
```

From my reading if not bound to any build phase, goals can be executed outside of the build lifecycle by direct invocation, the second way being to write plugins for the goals.

How would I identify if the goals have dependencies-- how would I go about writing a plug-in? I've been referring mostly to the maven guides on apache.org, but some of it is hard to follow.

Here is the pom file generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>${application.id}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${application.artifact}</artifactId>
  <version>${application.version}</version>
  <name>${application.name}</name>
  <inceptionYear>2007</inceptionYear>
  <organization>
    <name>OrganizationName</name>
    <url>http://organization.url</url>
  </organization>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:connection</connection>
    <url>http://svn.organization.local/svn/trunk/application_name</url>
  </scm>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <xmlPath>${basedir}/xdocs/changes.xml</xmlPath>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: 'mvn one:convert' is extremly old (2007 on the web site) I wouldn't expect it to work. Furthermore why are you going to Maven 2 instead of Maven3 ...Maven 1 and Maven 2/3 are not really related except the name. I would suggest to do the migration manually. How does your pom.xml file look like?

Comment: Thanks for your response. From all I've read manual migration looks to be my only option. Do you have any recommendations on good resources for this?